# Use Java Runtime to compile/run .java files?

Tags: java, runtime

Here is what I have done:-

```
// compile
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac C:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\Main.java");

// run
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java C:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\Main");
```

I am successfully able to compile this file but cannot run it. I have tried using `exec("cd C:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3")` before using `exec("java Main")` but to no benefit. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Java? 6 or 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ProcessBuilder`. Unlike `Runtime.exec()`, which you really should not use at all in modern code, a `ProcessBuilder` allows you to set up the directory in which the spawned process will run. `Runtime.exec()` does not give you this option.

Therefore:

```
final Path basePath = Paths.get("C:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3");

final Process compileProcess = new ProcessBuilder("javac", "Main.java")
    .directory(basePath.toFile())
    // other niceties of ProcessBuilder
    .start();

// check the status of the process; rinse, repeat
```